# How to find previous column value in current row sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the previous column value in a current row

| OrgID | Treelevel | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | immediateparent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | 3 | 008 | 009 | 0010 | NULL |
| 0012 | 2 | 0011 | 0012 |  |  |

Expected output

| OrgID | Treelevel | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | immediateparent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | 3 | 008 | 009 | 0010 | 009 |
| 0012 | 2 | 0011 | 0012 |  | 0011 |

This is my row in a table.

Here my orgid is 0010 and the higher level of 0010 is 009.

Now I want find the higher level of orgid and want to update in immediate parent column.please help me to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Please include the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  please check now

Comment: what dbms are you using? also, can you give us a  few more lines from the table?

Comment: @DannySlor are you asking about version or type

Comment: sql server, oracle, etc

Comment: @Dannyslor give me a min I will edit my questions and add few more values

Comment: @Priya I actually don't need more values, but I do need to know what system you're working with.

Comment: Sql server only

Comment: Use a `case` _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh pls give some example query

Comment: `case OrgID when LEVEL3 then LEVEL2 ...`

Comment: But @jarlh it is not only the two column values if level values is increased like upto 12 and I want to find the 11 th column value and update in immediate parent colum

Comment: Say eg max level is 12 in a row and previous level is level 11 so for that row I want to find one the level 11 values and have to update in immediate parent colum

Comment: 12 such columns. Seems like a less optimal design.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   orgid
        ,treelevel
        ,immediateparent
from 
         (
         select   orgid
                 ,treelevel
                 ,id
                 ,case when orgid = id then lag(id) over(partition by orgid order by level) end as immediateparent
         from     t
         unpivot (id for level in(LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3)) up
         ) t
where    orgid = id
```

| orgid | treelevel | immediateparent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 9 |
| 12 | 2 | 11 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/umx3oOt6)

Comment: @Priya let me know if it works for you or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking, the best practice for this would be if the row included a column indicating the parent Id. For example:

| **OrgID** | **OrgParentID** |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | :009 |
| 002 | :009 |
| 009 | :025 |

Thus we can query
select OrgID from table1 where OrgParentID = '009'
or to get the parent
select OrgParentID from table1 where OrgID = '001'
In order to follow the org structure further we would alias table1 for the next level:
select Org1.OrgID as level1,
Org1.OrgParentID as level2,
Org2.OrgParentID as level3
from Table1 as Org1
left outer join Table1 as Org2
on Org1.OrgParentID = Org2.OrgID

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hy, I'm not sure to get what you are trying to do...
Hope that's could help :

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST MYT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT T.ID,MAX(T.FIELD) AS MAX_VALUE 
     FROM
        (SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL1, LEN(MT.LEVEL1)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL2, LEN(MT.LEVEL2)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL3, LEN(MT.LEVEL3)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT)AS T GROUP BY ID) AS T ON T.ID = MYT.ID
```

This should show you the max value between your fields
As a good suggestion, it's always better to make the "SELECT" query first to be sure that the data you are managing is as expected

Here's the query for "UPDATE" :

```
UPDATE MYT SET MYT.immediateparent = MAX_VALUE
--    SELECT *
FROM TEST MYT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT T.ID,MAX(T.FIELD) AS MAX_VALUE 
     FROM
        (SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL1, LEN(MT.LEVEL1)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL2, LEN(MT.LEVEL2)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ID AS ID,
                CAST(RIGHT(MT.LEVEL3, LEN(MT.LEVEL3)-2) AS INT) AS FIELD
         FROM TEST MT)AS T GROUP BY ID) AS T ON T.ID = MYT.ID
```